# How to add the jQuery validation in textbox focusout event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-focusout

How to add the validation to textbox control in focusout event only?

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Show your current code that is doing the validation

Comment: Where's your code? what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#txt1").blur(function(){
  var v = $("#txt1").val();
  if(v == "test"){
    alert('valid');
  }
  else{
    alert('invalid');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
T1: <input type="text" id="txt1">
T2: <input type="text" id="txt2">
```

Refer: https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

```
.focusout(function() {

    // Put your validation code here
    if(!valid){
        return false;
    }    
})
```

**OR**

```
.blur(function() {

    // Put your validation code here
    if(!valid){
        return false;
    }    

})
```

Comment: If tried this way ,validation occurs on keyup event also

Comment: Please try code snippet. Is it what you want or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your html is:

```
<input type="text">
```

And your jQuery:

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
   //do smth with your text...
});
```